# Calculate$\phi(p,n)=\sum_{N}(-1)^{k+N}\sum_k\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(k+N)!} \frac{1}{(2k+N-1)!}(n(p-\frac{4\pi N}{3}))^{2k+N-1}\text{sgn}(p-\frac{4\pi N}{3})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there some way to calculate the series for arbitrary $p,n\in \mathcal{R}$
$$
\phi(p,n)=\sum_{N=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{2k+N}\frac{1}{k!(k+N)!} \frac{1}{(2k+N-1)!}\left(\frac{n}{4\pi}(p-\frac{4\pi N}{3})\right)^{2k+N-1}\text{sgn}(p-\frac{4\pi N}{3})
$$
I guess it converge because it converges faster than $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$ because the term $\frac{1}{(k+N-1)!}$ and the alternating term $(-1)^{k+N}$. But it is hard to get some analytic form for me because the $sgn$ term. Do you have some idea or can figure it out? The numerical one is also fine.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your $\phi(p,n)$ is of the form $\sum_{N=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{\color{red}k+N}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(k,N)$ where the $k$ in red is outside of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your remind! I have changed it@mathlove